# Is there a way to count the number of tweets that appear in an embedded timeline feed?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I have three embedded Twitter timeline feeds that I am tracking on a website and I'd like to be able to count the number of Tweets that appear in each of the respective embedded feeds. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What is `embedded Twitter timeline feeds`?

Comment: To be more precise...Embedded Timeline Feeds: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines